# Paparse error on parsing csv

Tags: express, papaparse

Hello I am using papaparse inside my express server and I am trying to parse a csv list and I am getting the following error :

```
{"data":[],"errors":[],"meta":{"delimiter":",","linebreak":"\n","aborted":false,"truncated":false,"cursor":11,"fields":["my-list.csv"]}}
```

Why am I seeing this?

```
// 1. Declare a GET route
 contactRouter.route('/contacts')
  .get(function(req, res){
    var responseJson = parser;

    res.send(responseJson);
    console.log(responseJson);
 });

// 2. Read the CSV file
var data = "my-list.csv";

var parser = Papa.parse(data, {
header: true,
delimiter: ",",
complete: function(results) {
   console.log(results);
 }
});
```

Comment: That's not an error. You're logging the results.

Comment: The data array seems empty though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error. It's the result of `console.log(responseJson);`.

Comment: Why am I not seeing the data on the list then?

Comment: Isn't the parsing async? I think it is

Comment: Indeed that was my mistake. Thank you